# UIAlertController not showing first time app is run

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I display a UIAlertController from the AppDelegate when a push notification is received and the app is open. The problem is, the alert does not show the first time the app is run. If you stop the app in Xcode and then re-start it, everything works as expected.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

   var alert: UIAlertController?

   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      self.showAlert(title: title,message:body,buttonTitle:"View",window:self.window!)
   }

   func showAlert(title: String,message : String,buttonTitle: String,window: UIWindow){
      self.alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
      alert?.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in

      //self.messageDelegate?.goToMessages()
   }))

   alert?.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

   window.rootViewController?.present(alert!, animated: false, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Comment: If your app is unactive, you recieve notification at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method. If your app is on background `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` method is triggered. Are you aware of this?

Comment: Is the notification is coming for the first time?

Comment: @ridvankucuk, yes I handle both scenarios. In the code about I show the userNotificationCenter function. The problem is that the code works fine after the first time the app is installed, but the first time, no Alert is shown.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed, yes the notification is delivered.

Comment: Is window's rootViewController instantiated the first time you call showAlert?

Comment: @RandyHill, if I do this:      topWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        topWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
        topWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        topWindow.rootViewController?.present(alert!, animated: true, completion: nil) The alert will show the first time but then the screen freezes. Is there something I need to reset?

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue. The first time the app is launched apparently your rootViewController hasn't been instantiated yet. I'd wait until it is instead of trying to force-instantiate it. I can't offer any better advice because your code is incomplete.

Comment: @RandyHill, I thought it might be a timing issue also, but the app is functioning before I send a test push notification.

Comment: @RandyHill, I'm wondering if it's just an Xcode testing issue.

Comment: The problem was I present the user with a registration screen the first time they use the app and used a segue back to the MainViewController instead of dismissing it.